# Moving a tab page to a different tab control

Tags: c#, user-interface, tabcontrol

I have a window with (amongst other things) 2 tab controls and I would like to allow the user to drag and drop tab pages from one tab control to the other.

When a tab control is empty, I want to hide it and expand the other one to take its place.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Ideally, a custom tab control with tabpage drag and drop support (similar to what is used by modern browsers, IDEs, etc.)

Comment: "Easy" as in "without writing any code"? No.

Comment: @CodyGray Finding a better tab control that would provide the functionality required (and possibly more) would be the best solution. Or some existing code. Every modern browser or IDE has a similar feature, so I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel. I could insert a new tab page in the tab control concerned, move and position the control(s) for the tabPage being dragged, remove the previous tab, etc. but without a whole lot of work, the end result won't feel as smooth as the many tab GUI people commonly use.